# Solving multiple errors with glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to fit an inverse gausiann distribution because my data looks like this:
[image]

Here is my current code for the model:

```
glm.full.odba  <- glmer(meanodba ~ AirTemp + LagAir + Radiation + Windspeed + LagRadiation + 
        + Precip + Raining + LULC + Elevation + (1 | Turtle),
      data = odba_fit_data_set, 
      family = inverse.gaussian(link = "log"))
```

Something is going wrong because I'm getting these errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.753051 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I tried adding  `glmerControl(optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb'))` but that actually just gave me even more errors to deal with.

Any ideas of how I can make this model work? I also then want to do a step wise selection hopefully using this  `lmerTest::step(glm.full.odba)`

Here's some of the data we're dealing with.

```
> dput(head(odba_fit_data_set))
structure(list(Turtle = c("R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12"), LULC = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), meanodba = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Elevation = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Radiation = c(-0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148), LagRadiation = c(-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148
), AirTemp = c(-1.61103364278686, -1.66486398863998, -1.54374571047046, 
-1.514908025192, -1.62256871689824, -1.73984197036397), LagAir = c(-1.49518745179209, 
-0.109267786452063, -1.67203156997695, -1.55093179339384, -1.522098513255, 
-1.62974275910666), Windspeed = c(-1.5432892339893, -1.18997289317795, 
-0.848219632611328, -1.05828225705735, -1.44436065856212, -1.3769093571345
), LagWind = c(-1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.18997289317795, 
-0.848219632611328, -1.05828225705735, -1.44436065856212), Precip = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Raining = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(odba_fit_data_set, 100))
structure(list(Turtle = c("R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", "R3L12", 
"R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12", "R3L1", "R3L12"), LULC = c(41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), meanodba = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), Elevation = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 282.51, NA, NA, NA, 282.76, NA, NA, NA, 281.96, NA, NA, NA, 
282.07, NA, NA, NA, 282.07, NA, NA, NA, 281.5, NA, NA, NA, 283.78, 
NA, NA, NA, 283.16, NA, NA, NA, 284.22, NA, NA, NA, 284.46, NA, 
NA, NA, 284.22, NA, NA, NA, 283.77, NA, NA, NA, 284.28, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Radiation = c(-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.721769590845183, -0.717883214459192, -0.698451332529236, -0.651814815897342, 
-0.589632793721484, -0.492473384071705, -0.37588209249197, -0.278722682842191, 
-0.232086166210297, -0.119381251016553, -0.10772212185858, 0.0283010516511109, 
0.210960741792696, 0.242051752880625, 0.35864304446036, 0.735621553901503, 
0.821121834393308, 1.20975947299242, 1.51289683109974, 1.7499657906452, 
2.24742196805206, 2.34458137770184, 2.33680862492986, 2.48837730398352, 
2.56221845531735, 2.62440047749321, 2.66326424135312, 2.72933263991497, 
2.74487814545893, 2.77596915654686, 2.713787134371, 2.73710539268695, 
2.73710539268695, 2.69435525244105, 2.65160511219515, 2.63217323026519, 
2.64383235942316, 2.45728629289559, 2.42230890542167, 2.34069500131585, 
1.83935244752299, 1.99480750296264, 2.02978489043656, 1.7460794142592, 
1.60228348797753, 1.42351017422194, 1.07373629948273, 1.12037281611463, 
0.918281244043087, 0.743394306673485, 0.556848240145909, 0.362529420846351, 
0.172096977932784, -0.0844038635426328, -0.302040941158138, -0.601291922879457, 
-0.651814815897342, -0.686792203371263, -0.721769590845183, -0.733428720003157, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148), LagRadiation = c(-0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.721769590845183, -0.717883214459192, 
-0.698451332529236, -0.651814815897342, -0.589632793721484, -0.492473384071705, 
-0.37588209249197, -0.278722682842191, -0.232086166210297, -0.119381251016553, 
-0.10772212185858, 0.0283010516511109, 0.210960741792696, 0.242051752880625, 
0.35864304446036, 0.735621553901503, 0.821121834393308, 1.20975947299242, 
1.51289683109974, 1.7499657906452, 2.24742196805206, 2.34458137770184, 
2.33680862492986, 2.48837730398352, 2.56221845531735, 2.62440047749321, 
2.66326424135312, 2.72933263991497, 2.74487814545893, 2.77596915654686, 
2.713787134371, 2.73710539268695, 2.73710539268695, 2.69435525244105, 
2.65160511219515, 2.63217323026519, 2.64383235942316, 2.45728629289559, 
2.42230890542167, 2.34069500131585, 1.83935244752299, 1.99480750296264, 
2.02978489043656, 1.7460794142592, 1.60228348797753, 1.42351017422194, 
1.07373629948273, 1.12037281611463, 0.918281244043087, 0.743394306673485, 
0.556848240145909, 0.362529420846351, 0.172096977932784, -0.0844038635426328, 
-0.302040941158138, -0.601291922879457, -0.651814815897342, -0.686792203371263, 
-0.721769590845183, -0.733428720003157, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, 
-0.737315096389148, -0.743828063935003, -0.737315096389148), 
    AirTemp = c(-1.61103364278686, -1.66486398863998, -1.54374571047046, 
    -1.514908025192, -1.62256871689824, -1.73984197036397, -1.66294147628808, 
    -1.72830689625259, -1.77252468034623, -1.83789010031073, 
    -1.88210788440437, -1.85327019912591, -1.73984197036397, 
    -1.6494838898248, -1.57066088339702, -1.45338762993129, -1.5168305375439, 
    -1.56489334634133, -1.6514064021767, -1.68216659980706, -1.68024408745516, 
    -1.62641374160204, -1.55912580928563, -1.47645777815405, 
    -1.39186723467057, -1.39763477172627, -1.38417718526299, 
    -1.33226935176176, -1.25344634533397, -1.18231338831378, 
    -1.07465269660753, -1.00351973958733, -0.947766881382312, 
    -0.905471609640573, -0.820881066157095, -0.774740769711561, 
    -0.703607812691363, -0.611327219800296, -0.501744015742153, 
    -0.367168151109346, -0.174916915919623, 0.0115667822144094, 
    0.148065159199113, 0.249958313849667, 0.430674474928007, 
    0.56140531485702, 0.667143494211368, 0.740198963583463, 0.765191624158127, 
    0.84016960588212, 0.878619852920064, 0.870929803512475, 0.932450198773187, 
    0.990125569330104, 1.04011089047943, 0.988203056978207, 1.09009621162876, 
    1.1343139957224, 1.14969409453757, 1.10163128574014, 1.13623650807429, 
    1.18237680451983, 1.17853177981603, 1.14777158218568, 1.23428463802105, 
    1.24389719978054, 1.26119981094761, 1.22851710096536, 1.24389719978054, 
    1.25543227389192, 1.22659458861346, 1.22274956390967, 1.16891921805655, 
    1.11893389690722, 1.10355379809204, 1.09394123633256, 0.968977933459234, 
    0.780571722973305, 0.565250339560814, 0.351851468500221, 
    0.178825356829469, 0.0884672762902993, 0.0154118069182044, 
    -0.0807138106766575, -0.259507459403101, -0.346020515238477, 
    -0.359478101701758, -0.486363916926975, -0.555574361595276, 
    -0.494053966334564, -0.542116775131995, -0.576721997466145, 
    -0.605559682744604, -0.622862293911679, -0.665157565653418, 
    -0.745903084433102, -0.829918469121882, -0.772818257359664, 
    -0.958914535979231, -0.899704072584881), LagAir = c(-1.49518745179209, 
    -0.109267786452063, -1.67203156997695, -1.55093179339384, 
    -1.522098513255, -1.62974275910666, -1.74699809833792, -1.67010935130103, 
    -1.73546478628239, 0.171376140232603, -1.84503125080996, 
    -1.88924228035618, -1.86040900021734, -0.78012210434897, 
    -1.65665382056957, -1.57784285485675, -1.46058751562549, 
    -1.52402073193093, -1.57207619882899, -1.65857603924549, 
    -1.68933153806025, -1.68740931938433, -1.6335871964585, -1.56630954280122, 
    -1.48365413973656, -1.39907651799597, -1.40484317402374, 
    -1.39138764329228, -1.33948773904238, -1.26067677332956, 
    -1.18955468232043, -1.08191043646878, -1.01078834545965, 
    -0.955044003857905, -0.912755192987613, -0.828177571247029, 
    -0.782044323024892, -0.710922232015764, -0.618655735571491, 
    -0.509089271043916, -0.37453396372935, -1.7796758158286, 
    0.00414311542735651, 0.140620641417845, 0.242498231241731, 
    0.423186786778433, 0.553897656741155, 0.659619683916884, 
    0.732663993601935, 0.757652836388925, 0.832619364749898, 
    0.871063738268345, 0.863374863564656, 0.924885861194172, 
    0.982552421471842, 1.03253010704582, 0.98063020279592, 1.08250779261981, 
    1.12671882216602, 1.1420965715734, 1.09404110467534, 1.12864104084194, 
    1.17477428906408, 1.17092985171223, 1.14017435289748, 1.22667419331398, 
    1.23628528669359, 1.2535852547769, 1.22090753728622, 1.23628528669359, 
    1.24781859874913, 1.21898531861029, 1.21514088125845, 1.16131875833262, 
    1.11134107275864, 1.09596332335126, 1.08635222997165, 0.961408016036696, 
    0.773030585796304, 0.557742094092999, 0.344375821065616, 
    -1.74699809833792, 0.0810318624642517, 0.00798755277920185, 
    -0.0881233810169166, -0.266889717877697, -0.353389558294204, 
    -0.366845089025661, -0.493711521636537, -0.562911393969742, 
    -0.501400396340226, -0.549455863238286, -0.584055799404888, 
    -0.612889079543723, -0.630189047627025, -0.672477858497317, 
    -0.809398910098875, -0.753211042886056, 0.203206241041648, 
    0.242498231241731), Windspeed = c(-1.5432892339893, -1.18997289317795, 
    -0.848219632611328, -1.05828225705735, -1.44436065856212, 
    -1.3769093571345, -1.13344227864813, -1.5432892339893, -1.32487549603319, 
    -1.19061528652488, -1.11417047824024, -0.856570746121415, 
    -0.687621295878894, -0.703681129552137, -0.814815178570982, 
    -0.736443190245554, -0.777556364449057, -0.904107853794215, 
    -1.03258652318016, -1.47712271925554, -1.35185601660424, 
    -1.29404061538056, -0.828947832203436, -0.822523898734138, 
    -1.35249840995117, -1.28440471517662, -1.21566862705514, 
    -1.28440471517662, -1.08462038428147, -1.26127855468715, 
    -1.20988708693277, -0.956784108242453, -0.817384751958701, 
    -0.89190238020255, -0.511605518820146, -0.606679734165747, 
    -0.413961730086826, -0.407537796617529, -0.432591137147789, 
    -0.591904687186363, -0.679270182368807, -0.644580941634602, 
    -0.239230739721938, -0.402398649842091, -0.150580457845635, 
    -0.577772033553909, -0.198117565518435, 0.112158421048627, 
    0.0960985873753839, 0.284319838025797, 0.59266864455207, 
    0.612582838306892, -0.054863849153104, 0.553482650389356, 
    0.261193677536326, 0.423076800962619, -0.622097174492061, 
    -0.00796913482723329, 0.121794321252573, 0.588814284470491, 
    -0.311821187924998, 0.0247929258661831, 0.611298051613032, 
    -0.457644477678049, 0.488600922349452, -0.246939459885095, 
    0.312585145290705, 0.219438109985893, -0.252078606660533, 
    0.0639789200288969, 0.133357401497308, -0.451862937555681, 
    0.265690430964834, 0.482176988880155, -0.410107370005248, 
    -0.901538280406496, -0.343298461924555, -1.43472475835818, 
    -1.49189776623492, -1.50924238660203, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.54014119191596, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.54014119191596, -1.5432892339893), LagWind = c(-1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.18997289317795, -0.848219632611328, 
    -1.05828225705735, -1.44436065856212, -1.3769093571345, -1.13344227864813, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.32487549603319, -1.19061528652488, -1.11417047824024, 
    -0.856570746121415, -0.687621295878894, -0.703681129552137, 
    -0.814815178570982, -0.736443190245554, -0.777556364449057, 
    -0.904107853794215, -1.03258652318016, -1.47712271925554, 
    -1.35185601660424, -1.29404061538056, -0.828947832203436, 
    -0.822523898734138, -1.35249840995117, -1.28440471517662, 
    -1.21566862705514, -1.28440471517662, -1.08462038428147, 
    -1.26127855468715, -1.20988708693277, -0.956784108242453, 
    -0.817384751958701, -0.89190238020255, -0.511605518820146, 
    -0.606679734165747, -0.413961730086826, -0.407537796617529, 
    -0.432591137147789, -0.591904687186363, -0.679270182368807, 
    -0.644580941634602, -0.239230739721938, -0.402398649842091, 
    -0.150580457845635, -0.577772033553909, -0.198117565518435, 
    0.112158421048627, 0.0960985873753839, 0.284319838025797, 
    0.59266864455207, 0.612582838306892, -0.054863849153104, 
    0.553482650389356, 0.261193677536326, 0.423076800962619, 
    -0.622097174492061, -0.00796913482723329, 0.121794321252573, 
    0.588814284470491, -0.311821187924998, 0.0247929258661831, 
    0.611298051613032, -0.457644477678049, 0.488600922349452, 
    -0.246939459885095, 0.312585145290705, 0.219438109985893, 
    -0.252078606660533, 0.0639789200288969, 0.133357401497308, 
    -0.451862937555681, 0.265690430964834, 0.482176988880155, 
    -0.410107370005248, -0.901538280406496, -0.343298461924555, 
    -1.43472475835818, -1.49189776623492, -1.50924238660203, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5432892339893, -1.5399596218877, 
    -1.5432892339893, -1.5399596218877, -1.5432892339893), Precip = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Raining = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There appear to be variables in your data that are not in your model, others that are constant, and others that are full of NA values.  That alone will create problems with any software.  Do you think you could create a smaller, cleaner, focused dataset to demonstrate your question?

Comment: @whuber I tried to slim down the data and now dput is giving me a small enough code to paste. Not really sure why since I actually made the data set much smaller.

Comment: I still see loads of junk and irrelevant variables in that data structure.

Comment: @whuber just edited it again. I tried taking out the rows with NA but then dput wouldn't work.